# Is it allowed to separate infinite sums?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Just a quick question, is it allowed to separate infinite sums. For example I want to prove that $\sum \frac{n-1}{n^2}$ diverges as follows: 
$$
\sum \frac{n-1}{n^2} = \sum \left( \frac{n}{n^2} - \frac{1}{n^2} \right) = \sum \frac{1}{n} - \sum  \frac{1}{n^2} \geq \sum \frac{1}{n} -2 = +\infty, 
$$
Since $\sum \frac{1}{n^2} \leq 2$ and $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges. Is this valid? I'm not sure because of the infinity of the sums, for finite sums this is allowed of course.

Comment: It is valid under some circumstances, but not under all.  For example, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (a_n+b_n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n + \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ will be true if $a_n\geq 0$ and $b_n\geq 0$ for all $n$.  You run into problems when dealing with conditionally convergent series though.  I don't remember the exact full list of conditions of when it is or isn't allowed, but I generally try to avoid it in the first place.

Comment: It is allowed whenever it does not generate indeterminate forms such as $+ \infty - \infty$, or oscillating series.

Comment: Thanks guys. @Crostul, I take it that then it is not allowed in this case right? Additionally, what about taking a constant in front of the sum? For example in which cases can we do this kind of thing: $\sum \frac{3n}{n^3} = 3 \sum  \frac{n}{n^3}$?

Comment: There is no need to separate terms here.   $\frac {n-1}{n^2}=\frac {1-1/n}{n}≥\frac 1{2n}$ for $n≥2$ is already enough.

Comment: It's not allowed directly but it is allowed as a contradiction.  If $\sum \frac {n-1}{n^2}$ converged then it would be allowed and we'd get $\sum \frac 1n + \sum \frac 1{n^2}$ which would converge but as $\sum \frac 1{n^2}$ converges then so would $\sum \frac 1n$ .. but it doesn't so we can so it must diverge. i.e.  If $\sum (a + b)$ and $\sum b$ converges but $\sum a$ diverges we can conclude that $\sum (a+b)$ diverges *via contradiction* (!not! by direct calculation).

Comment: Nice distinction between proof by calculation and proof by contradiction! Quite stunning that one works and the other doesn't, even though the differences are minor :)

Comment: Well.... it goes back to those horrible abuses we did in the fifth grade (or at least I did).  $\infty + 1 = \infty$ and $\infty - 1 = \infty$ and $\infty + \infty = \infty$ but $\infty -\infty = WTFK$.  So we have here $\infty + 1 = \infty$.  Only problem is... we were crap mathematicians in the fifth grade and doing horrible and imprecise crimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone correct me if I am wrong.

If we know the behaviors of $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ and want to figure out the behavior of $\sum (a_n + b_n)$ from them...

If you have $\sum (a_n + b_n)$ and $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ both converge then $\sum a_n + \sum b_n = \sum (a_n + b_n)$ and so it is allowed.

If you have $\sum (a_n + b_n)$ and $\sum a_n$ diverges but $\sum b_n$ converges we can conclude by contradiction that $\sum (a_n + b_n)$ diverges but *NOT* because we can separate $\sum(a_n + b_n) = \sum a_n + b_n$-- we can *NOT* do that--- but because *IF* $\sum(a_n + b_n)$ converged we *would* be able to separate $\sum a_n + \sum b_n$ and that sum would converge, which it does not so that is a contradiction. So we can conclude $\sum(a_n + b_n) $ does not converge.

And if we have $\sum (a_n + b_n)$ and $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ fail to converge then ... we got nothing.  There's nothing we can conclude.

At least I *think* that is correct.

If on the other hand we know the behavoir of $\sum (a_n + b_n)$ and the behavior of $\sum b_n$ and want to figure out the behavior of $\sum a_n$ we can do similar:.

If $\sum (a_n + b_n)$ converges and $\sum b_n$ converge then $\sum (a_n + b_n) - \sum b_n = \sum (a_n + b_n - b_n) = \sum a_n $ converges is allowed.

If $\sum (a_n + b_n)$ diverges and $\sum b_n$ converges we can assume by contradiction that $a_n$ doesn't converge.  If it did $\sum a_n + \sum b_n = \sum (a_n + b_n)$ would converge but it doesn't.

If $\sum (a_n + b_n)$ converges but $\sum b_n$ does not then by contradiction $a_n$ does not.  If is did we could have $\sum (a_b + b_n) - \sum a_n = \sum (a_b + b_n - a_n) = \sum b_n$ converges.  But it doesn't.

And finaly if $\sum (a_n + b_n)$ diverges and $\sum b_n$ diverges we can't do or conclude  anything.

Comment: Even if $\sum (a_n+b_n)$ converges we cannot do that. Only when one of the sums $\sum a_n$ or $\sum b_n$ converges then we can do that. I'd say is more like assuming $\sum (a_n+b_n)$ converges, and we have clearly that $\sum a_n$ converges, then we must have $\sum b_n$ convergent to $\sum (a_n+b_n) - \sum a_n $

Comment: @Adam, that would mean in the example case it is allowed since $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges? So the proof is correct?

Comment: If we would to assume that $\sum \frac{n-1}{n^2} $ is convergent then yes

Comment: Adam, yes,  I was only assuming the behavior of $\sum a$ and $\sum b$ were known and drawing the conclusion of $\sum a + b$ from those.

Comment: If $\sum \frac {n-1}{n^2} \to k$  and we know that $\sum \frac 1{n^2} \to m$ then we would conclude $\sum (\frac {n-1}{n^2} + \frac 1{n^2}) =\sum \frac 1n \to k  +m $.  Which it does not. So this is a valid proof by contradiction that $\sum \frac {n-1}{n^2}$ does not converge.

Comment: I've been informally treating "not converge" = "diverge".  You may want to check your book if you definitions are the same..

Comment: Yeah I thought hose terms were opposites, as in: a series does not converge it has to diverge and vice versa. But I'm not sure, it is also possible maybe that $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n$ does not exist

Comment: Converge means that $\lim_{n\to \infty} s_n = k$ for some real $k$.  If $s_n$ does not converge that does not mean that $\lim_{n\to \infty} s_n = \pm \infty$.  Everything I wrote works for both interpretations  but I was meaning "doesn't converge".